# Trigger Azure Devops Release pipeline from Jenkins without using TFS plugin

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

Brief background. My team uses Jenkins for CI but (among other things) we pass our output to Azure Devops Release pipelines, to be used for downstream testing. We currently have a working system for this but it uses the Jenkins Team Foundation Server/TFS plugin (to trigger the Azure Devops release) and specific features of azure-pipelines-tasks (to pull the artifacts from Jenkins). The issue is that the former is deliberately disabled in recent versions of Jenkins (for licencing and security issues) and the latter similarly has a bug talking to Jenkins. Basically we are stuck on Jenkins 2.263.1 with no sign that this will be rectified. It would seem prudent to use a completely different approach.

Intuitively we need to be able to programmatically trigger the release pipeline. Additionally I need to transfer the artifact - whether Jenkins would push or ADevops would pull, I don't know - guess the latter as closer to current. Whatever, I am wondering if somebody already has instructions on how to do this to avoid us re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Not really sure. The references below seem to refer to running Jenkins within a ADevops environment, which is not what we are really doing - we have a completely separate Jenkins build system that links to ADevops release pipelines, mainly to populate an overall test environment with latest versions.
However, it has got me thinking that we have a separate activity at the moment to migrate all our repos onto github and I am now wondering what is going to happen to those release pipelines. Looking further internally. Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently trying to use curl to post to the endpoint directly. Something like:

curl -X POST -f     -H "Authorization: Basic ${SERVICE_TOKEN_B64}"     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"definitionId\":${RELEASE_DEFINITION_ID},\"description\":\"Triggered by #544\",\"isDraft\":false}"     "${AZURE_URL}/${ORGANISATION}/${PROJECT_NAME}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0"

Issue is that this is consistently returning error 400. Have raised a separate issue on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the Azure REST API, chiefly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), and some experimentation, I can report what I got to work.

Because the original job was Traditional/Freestyle (the plugin did not support pipelines), I kept the job but replaced the plugin step with a bash script, run at after the "archive" step I had in there anyway. The key statement in this script is:

```
curl -X POST -f \
-H "Authorization: Basic ${SERVICE_TOKEN_B64}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"definitionId\":${RELEASE_DEFINITION_ID},\"description\":\"Triggered by ${BUILD_TAG}\",\"isDraft\":false,\"artifacts\":[{\"alias\":\"_${JOB_BASE_NAME}\",\"instanceReference\":{\"id\":\"${BUILD_NUMBER}\",\"name\":\"${BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}\"}}]" \
-o output.json \
"${AZURE_URL}/${ORGANISATION}/${PROJECT_NAME}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0"
```

The various macros are mainly set in an "Inject Environment Variables" above.
AZURE_URL here is "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com", but could be something else I guess if you had your own Enterprise instance of Azure. ORGANISATION and PROJECT_NAME should be obvious.

Less obvious is RELEASE_DEFINITION_ID. You can go through and enquire this from the REST API, given then name of the release (pipeline) you are dealing with - essentially, release definition in the API equates to release pipeline in the Web UI. However, the simplest approach is to navigate in the Web UI to the release pipeline you are interested in (not an individual release job/instance). If you look at the URL for this, you will see definitionId=XXX as a parameter. You want the XXX value.

SERVICE_TOKEN_B64 is a suitable PAT manipulated into a different format. What you actually want is to take the output of:

```
printf "%s"":$PAT" | base64
```

and save that as secret text in the Jenkins credentials system. Note that the plugin can do this on the fly (using the username and PAT from the credentials system), but if you do that in a bash script it will (typically) show this modified token in the log - which sort of defeats the object.

This leaves the artifacts. It took me quite a while to discover i) you need the artifacts and ii) the payload is quite important. We have what I assume is a fairly standard setup where there is a "Jenkins" Artifact on the Azure release pipeline. We have "Specify at time of release creation" for the Default Version - I didn't set the Azure release pipeline up, but I suspect all fairly standard too. With this, the artifact part is crucial and without it (or setting to an empty array) I was getting 400 errors which baffled me - I raised a parallel question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096872/attempt-to-create-an-azure-release-run-azure-release-pipeline-release-returns-er). Looking back the scenario is fairly straightforward. The artifacts payload itself is:

```
[{"alias":"_${JOB_BASE_NAME}","instanceReference":{"id":"${BUILD_NUMBER}","name":"${BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}"}}]
```

The alias value is that of the Artifact name in the Azure release pipeline - not sure if just prefixing the job with "_" is standard or just the convention used by the guy who set the pipeline up. The other values could I think be treated as magic, but my guess is that the "id" is the actual value used of the Jenkins job instance from where the artifact itself is pulled (the Jenkins job name comes from the Azure pipeline setting) and the "name" is used for displaying/logging. As said, this works for our purposes but your usage may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [TEE-CLC](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/tag/14.135.0) and invoke the CLI commands from a shell?

That seems to be MS suggestion for their Azure plugins which they have formally [announced abandoning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-usupdates/jenkins-plugins-for-azure-are-being-retired-on-29-february-2024/).

Of course, now they have quietly announced they [won't maintain that either](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere), so I guess the implied message is "go use github?"