# Attempt to create an Azure release/run Azure release pipeline release returns error 400

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a release (from my viewpoint kick off a release pipeline) using the REST API. Background to this is that it should run on our Jenkins system - we currently use the old TFS plugin for this function, but that needs to be removed from our system and this is the one thing that is stopping us. I am trying to use curl directly to call the API. I originally had issues with authentication (was trying to use "-u username:PAT" but have now switched to passing base64(":PAT") as the authorization header and things seem to have moved on.

I am now consistently getting 400 errors, which are reportedly bad data. It seems valid json so I am wondering if is something missing. Issue (at least for me) is that the doc on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 does not state what fields are required for the body and what are optional. I have to assume descriptionId is required and some others are optional but it is not that clear:)

This is not Jenkins per se - I get the same error making the call manually from bash. My current curl line looks like:

curl -X POST -f -H 'Authorization: Basic ${BASE64}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"definitionId":27,"description":"Triggered by local","isDraft":false}' 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${ORGANIZATION}/${PROJECT}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0'

The 27 I got from the Web UI for the particular release pipeline (.../release?definitionId=27&view=mine&_a=releases - I assume that is correct). Now baffled. Is there a way of getting more useful error info? Anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few pointers, and some experiments, I think I've managed to the bottom of this. Confusingly the error codes can relate to the processing. Thus, for example, if I try and use a definitionId of "1" (instead of "27"), you get a 404 error - nothing to do with an invalid/unknown url and everything to do with the posted data.

The actual issue here turned out to be that the artifacts: field was missing. This has to be both present and valid - just adding "artifacts":[] was not sufficient. As said, I was trying to trigger something that had been setup to talk to Jenkins. With my setup, seems I need to add:

```
"artifacts": [{"alias": "_${JOB_BASE_NAME}", "instanceReference": {"id": "${BUILD_NUMBER}", "name": "${BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}"}}]
```

Not sure quite how generic this is (esp. the alias) but that seems to work for me so far.